# Template output singe fields from entity reference fields from other content type

Tags: 7, views

I have "Carousel" content that calls another "news" content type. I created the view that shows the teaser of the single news. I would like to create an html inside the .tpl "views-view-field---insights-cosousel-5-elements" by printing the individual fields of the array.

I printed the array via

```
<? php print render ($ render_array); ?>
```

Now I would like to print the single news fields inside a specific html.

This is a Content type "Carousel" with inside Entity Reference of "News"
[image]

This is a views thet prin teaser of content type "News"

[image]

This is a setting of teaser of "News"

[image]

How can I print the individual fields of the entity reference array using PHP?

I searched but I didn't find a useful example.

Comment: Just render the referenced node in its appropriate view mode.

Comment: Hi Apaderno
please you give me an example code like this: <?php echo($row->_field_data['nid']['entity']); ?>
thanks!!!

Comment: Resolve
New View of content type "approfondimenti" that inside has the reference field  

In the view I have add relationship with "Entity Reference: approfondimenti" the field thet reference of content type "approfondimenti" that is "linked" to content type "news"

And now is possible add single field in view